# Instead of forEach how can I use .map(), .reduce(), and .filter() to make my code concise lest brittle?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter, foreach, reduce

I am taking an array of objects (let raw), grabbing value by displayName and inserting it into (const defaultCirclePackStructure) by displayName this is for d3 circle packing. Here is [Codepen](https://codepen.io/lavebug/pen/JzvqVv)

```
let convertMetricDataToD3 = (arrayMetricData) => {
  var circlePackData = defaultCirclePackStructure
  let operationSumTime = 0

  arrayMetricData.forEach(element => {
    insertMetricData(element, circlePackData)
    if(element.displayName === "Equipment Uptime" || element.displayName === "Equipment  Downtime"){
      operationSumTime+=element.value
    }
  });

  circlePackData.children[0].children[1].value = 
Math.round(operationSumTime) + "%"
  return circlePackData;
}
```

It works, but its so brittle and inefficient, how can I improve it by using map, reduce, filter or anything else.

Comment: The code may be strange and somewhat hard to read, but it's not *inefficient*, this looks more suited for Code Review than here

Comment: For starters, I would decide whether or not you want to use semicolons, and then use them or don't. You're either missing six, or you have one extra.

Comment: @cdhowie edited accordingly. The code was a mess!

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira He's asking how to improve his code; we shouldn't be editing it or it effectively changes the question. I'm going to restore the original version (which was already altered, apparently, by the time either of us got here).

Comment: @cdhowie the code was not event readable, was badly edited, and the OP is asking merely for performance issues

Comment: Regardless, editing the code for them doesn't help them improve at all.  When asking for a code review, all input is valid. (And I missed that you're the one who did the original edit. Fixing up the backticks is fine; reformatting the code or adding semicolons is not fine.)

Comment: Clarification no semicolons, agree code is a mess. I also use switch since I need to take only values and fit it into this existing array of objects which is brittle. Any suggestions on improving it? I would like to figure out how not to use that defaultCirclePackStructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off your Pen, I was able to create the following that's a little more maintainable.

```
const convertMetricDataToD3 = (arrayMetricData) => {

  const circlePackData = defaultCirclePackStructure;
  arrayMetricData.forEach(element => insertMetricData(element, circlePackData));

  const trackedOperations = [
    'Equipment Uptime',
    'Equipment Downtime',
  ];

  const operationSumTime = arrayMetricData
    .filter(({displayName}) => trackedOperations.includes(displayName))
    .map(({value})=> value)
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b);

  circlePackData.children[0].children[1].value = Math.round(operationSumTime) + "%";

  return circlePackData;
}
```

Comment: Is there a better way instead of having default (defaultCirclePackStructure) object json and inserting values with switch (insertMetricData) just build that collection?

Comment: Yes, if you store references to all your operations in an object, with the names as keys, then you could do: `operationMap[operationName].value = Math.round(metricObject.value) + '%'` and the same for the size without requiring the switch statement.